# What versions of linux work on Dell dimension 4600 i386 system

Tags: dell

My 1st install was on a Dell Dimension 4600i 386 2002 vintage machine.
I tried Ubuntu 16.04 -desktop-i386, which was slow, especially from keyboard...like 1-2 characters/min. - I suspected the problem may have been keyboard entry related.
I next tried Linix Lite-2.8-32 bit, which had hang ups with US english translation, google & google chrome issues.
Eventually I got it to work well for a short time, but following an update, it ground to a halt.
As a standard feature it would not display a sign-in screen at start-up for entry code, did display a p/w entry box though.  Re-install did not help, it seemed as if original issues were re-introduced.... seems logical..

**My questions are:**

1. I liked LL 2.8 when it worked, is it possible to alter its processes to run reliably?
2. What other versions of linux systems will work better on my system?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This is sadly not how this site works, if you want an discussion you might have a look into [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org). For a question and answer site your question is simply to broad and/or generates only opinion based answers.

Comment: will rephrase naxt time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: Sorry, but you shouldn't ask two questions in 1 question. Ask them seperately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should install Lubuntu 14.04.

Here's a direct link to the latest ISO image: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-i386.iso

Comment: Is 14.04 necessary for a Dell 64bit 2006 vintage machine also?

Comment: @db_Design - No, but I do think it might run a tad faster. It still has support until 2018.

Comment: encountered an error with "unsafe swap space" how to rectify?

Comment: @db_Design - That's a different question.